# Proving the existence of nonprincipal ultrafilter on Nat

Tags: proof-verification, set-theory

> Prove that all subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ can be labeled as either "large" or "small", where
>
> 1. $A \subset \mathbb{N} \text{ is large} \iff \overline{A} \text{ is small}$.
> 2. If $A$ is large, then any superset of $A$ is large, and if $A$ is small, any subset of $A$ is small.
> 3. Union of two small subsets is small, intersection of two large subsets is large.
> 4. All finite subsets are small, all subsets with finite complements are large.

Now forget about the fourth condition for a moment.

Let "partial labeling" be such a labeling where some of the subsets are unlabeled. Consider the set $\mathcal{L}$ of all partial labelings $L$ of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$  and partially order it by inclusion: $L_1 \leq L_2$ if $L_2$ has the same labels as $L_1$ for those sets that are labeled in $L_1$.

Now, for any totally ordered subset $S$ of $\mathcal{L}$ consider the union $U = \cup_{L \in S} L$ of all the labelings of that subset. It can be easily seen that $U$ is a proper labeling (for every set that has a label in $U$ there exists a labeling $L$ in $S$ such that (1) and (2) hold, and for every pair of sets there exists $L$ in $S$ containing both of them, so (3) holds).

In other words, we have proven the precondition of Zorn's lemma that every chain has an upper bound, so for every partial labeling $L$ there exists a maximal labeling agreeing with $L$. Clearly, being maximal, this labeling would be defined on every subset of $\mathbb{N}$.

Now let's recall about (4) and take $L$ to be such that (4) holds: label all finite subsets as small and their complements as large, and take the maximal element $M_L \geq L$. That would be the nonprincipal ultrafilter on $\mathbb{N}$.

Is this reasoning correct?

---

It was noted in the comments that one need to show that there indeed are no unlabeled subsets in $M_L$ as it's not that clear. I tried to prove the original claim inductively first by considering $L$ satisfying (4) and then showing that we could inductively take any yet unlabeled $A \subset \mathbb{N}$ and label it so that (1-3) hold.

The way I was doing that is by considering any other already labeled $B \subset \mathbb{N}$ and trying to show that there is no contradiction if either $B \subset A$, $A \subset B$ or $A \neq B, A \cap B \neq \emptyset$. But this is clumsy and perhaps unnecessary in this case. What would be an elegant way to show that $M_L$ does not contain any unlabeled subsets?

Comment: The idea looks right, but there are two questionable points. (1) "Clearly, being maximal, this labeling would be defined on every subset of $\mathbb N$." Is that really so clear? If it weren't defined on all subsets, you could enlarge it as a function, but can you do it while preserving the first three requirements (especially the 3rd)? (2) I'm not sure what "the maximal element **for** this labeling" means; I hope you meant a maximal element $\geq$ this labeling.

Comment: Re (2) — thanks, of course, corrected! Re (1) — I updated the post, thanks for noting this!

Comment: A filter $f$ is free iff $\cap f$ is empty. To prove existece of a free  ultrafilter on an infinite set $S$: Let $F$ be the set of free filters on $S$. The Frechet filter on $S$ belongs to  $F$ so $F$ is not empty.  For $f,g\in F$ let $f<_Fg\iff f\subsetneqq g.$  Then $<_F$ is transitive. If $C$ is a non-empty $<_F$-chain then $\bigcup C\in F$ and $\bigcup C$ is a $<_F$-upper bound for $C.$  By Zorn let $f\in F$ be  $<_F$-maximal. Then $f$ is not a proper subset of any member of $F$, and if $h$ is a non-free filter on $S$ then $\neg (f\subset h) $ else $\cap f\supset \cap h\ne \emptyset.$